# Get list of file changes from GitHub repository using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github-actions

I am creating a GitHub workflow in which I am using `paths:` as changes specific file change event.
I have added multiple path as couple file there, and need to detect which file committed.

```
  push:
    branches: [main]
    paths:
      - 'ABC/text1.yaml'
      - 'XYZ/text2.yaml'
      - 'MNO/text3.yaml'
```

Now, after specifying above path I am trying to detect which path file changed. for that I am using
below command into the steps

```
 commit_hash=${{github.sha}}
 changed_files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit_hash)
 echo "Last commit changed files: $changed_files"
```

It's working file on local, showing last committed file so I can compare with the paths to detect file. But on GitHub Workflow it getting "" (empty). not getting any error, check Last commit hash as well.

Tried with & without specifying branch as there is couple of branches.

Also tried with below to get latest hash, but still same result.

```bash
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"
```

Along with above I tried with

```bash
git show --pretty="" --name-only $commit_hash
```

but here getting all changes of all commit which is not the requirement.

Comment: I would suggest using [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) action to identify changed files in the workflow. It should be useful in your case and abstract part of the complexity.